# Using query to check contain data from table A

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have 2 table, table A and table B. First I select single column from table A by using the following query:

```
Dim loadName = From a In db.Staff Where a.Rank = "E" Select a.Name
```

The data contain `N1`,`N2`,`N3`,`N4`. Then I write second query to select all Name from Account table which contain Name in Staff table, In my Account table contain data:

```
AccountNo | Name
------------------
A001      | N2
A002      | N3
A003      | T1
```

I using query as below to select all account from Account table:

```
Dim loadAcc= From b In db.ACCOUNT Where b.AccountName.Contain(loadName.Any) Select b
```

The Expected result should be as below:

```
AccountNo | Name
------------------
A001      | N2
A002      | N3
```

But I cannot get the expected result. Any mistake in my query? Thanks

Comment: Did you solve you're problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple `JOIN` is what you need here:

```
Dim results = From a In db.Account
              Join s In db.Staff On a.Name Equals s.Name
              Select a
```

Answer (score 0):

Loadname.any result in true if there are any elements.

first part checks if accountname contains true.

I think you can do it the other way arround.

where loadname.contains(b.accountname)